# Upsert that creates foreign key if it doesn't exist

Tags: python, sql, postgresql, database-design, asyncpg

This schema stores playcounts of Albums/Artists/Tracks for a community of Last.FM users. Users can "index" their account to update playcounts and keep leaderboards accurate.

Data from Last.FM is inserted into staging tables (using COPY which is faster than execute many). Once data has been inserted a query moves all staging records to the final ***user_x*** table (let's call it the migration phase). This query is causing high CPU usage. Furthermore, updates aren't made most of the time and I'm not sure why. I [analyzed the query](https://explain.depesz.com/s/ZAIk) to confirm migration is the problem. What is a better method of doing this?

Update records where user has playcounts, then insert the rest:

```
with updated as (
 UPDATE user_artists
 SET listens = sg.listens
 FROM user_artists_staging sg
    WHERE sg.user_id = $1
 AND user_artists.artist_id = (SELECT id FROM artists WHERE name = sg.name LIMIT 1)
 AND user_artists.user_id = sg.user_id
RETURNING user_artists.user_id, user_artists.artist_id
)
                        
INSERT INTO user_artists(user_id, artist_id, listens)
    SELECT user_artists_staging.user_id, fetch_artist(user_artists_staging.name) AS artist_id, user_artists_staging.listens
    FROM user_artists_staging
       LEFT JOIN updated t ON artist_id = t.artist_id
       WHERE user_artists_staging.user_id = $1
GROUP BY user_artists_staging.user_id, name, listens
ON CONFLICT ON CONSTRAINT user_artists_pkey DO NOTHING;

CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION fetch_artist(name VARCHAR)
RETURNS SETOF INT AS $$
    BEGIN
        RETURN QUERY SELECT id FROM artists WHERE LOWER(artists.name) = LOWER(fetch_artist.name) LIMIT 1;
        IF NOT FOUND THEN
            RETURN QUERY INSERT INTO artists (name)
                VALUES (fetch_artist.name)
                ON CONFLICT ON CONSTRAINT artists_name_key DO NOTHING
                RETURNING id;
        end if;
END; $$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

Schema:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS user_artists (
    user_id BIGINT,
    artist_id INT, 
    listens INT,
    
    PRIMARY KEY (user_id, artist_id),

    FOREIGN KEY (user_id) REFERENCES users(id) ON DELETE CASCADE,
    FOREIGN KEY (artist_id) REFERENCES artists(id) ON DELETE CASCADE
);

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS user_artists_staging (
    user_id BIGINT NOT NULL,
    name VARCHAR,
    listens INTEGER
);
```

Comment: you should, use merge https://www.postgresql.org/message-id/attachment/23520/sql-merge.html and try your luck there, i still think that you are missing some indexes at least on user_artists_staging  You need one user_id, name

Comment: @nbk Thank you I shall give merge a go. 
About the indexes, I thought it would be best to leave staging as a raw table to speed up COPY into it, as user_artists has all the indexes, user_artists_staging is an intermediary table which later gets cleared.

Comment: Queries that are slow, needs indexes, so oyu should still think about it

Comment: [MERGE](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/15/sql-merge.html) does not exist in current production versions of Postgres. It is in the dev version 15. The link posted refers to a   development version of a now long dead Postgres version(8.4) in which `MERGE` never appeared in the production release.

Comment: I've changed the query to use ON CONFLICT and use the excluded field to access the column needed from the staging table. This approach is much faster and works fine.